# PHP script executing Shell Command in Linux and using script to reply any interactive prompt from system for example password

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am writing a PHP script to automatically helps the user copy the server's public ssh key to another remote server so as to facilitate easily authentication without password in future.

```
$cmd = 'sudo ssh-copy-id -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote_server';
$reply = shell_exec($cmd);
  echo  $reply;
```

The reply from the server supposed to be "The Authenticity of the host 'XXX.xxx.xxx.xxx' Cannot be established.........

But instead the $reply was empty.
How do I read the reply from the server and have my script to continue inputting the answer. Making the entire process automated?

Comment: Does your command work when you run it from your prompt?  As its tough to say if your getting an error or no output.  So i would start with testing and ensuring the command works and isnt returning an error.

Comment: you should aim at something non-interactive on the PHP end. Like you could run an `expect script` that would do the interactive work outside PHP

Comment: Hi jgetner, yes I tried it it works when I am manually inputting the details.

Comment: Hi ron, I was reading about something like that. Is it writing a bash script with the expect function? I am not very proficient in this. Do you know where I can find out more?